# Python and R Packages: Documentation together

Tags: python, documentation-generation, pkgdown

I'm working on a package that has R and python versions.

For the R package I used pkgdown for documentation.
I would like to keep pkgdown because of the design and ease to use.

Which is the best way to put the documentation for R and python together?